# Forward mail success to another page

Tags: php

on this php sendmail how would I make it so when the email is sent I forward it to a URL instead of just saying "THanks your message has been sent."  I can't figure it out for the life of me.  I tried

```
header("Locations: URL")
```

but that didn't seem to work.  Here is my full code

```
<?php

$name = trim($_POST['name']);
$email = $_POST['email'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];

$site_owners_email = 'email@example.com'; // Replace this with your own email   address
$site_owners_name = 'example'; // replace with your name

if (strlen($name) < 2) {
    $error['name'] = "Please enter your name";  
}

if (!preg_match('/^[a-z0-9&\'\.\-_\+]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z0-9\-]+\.)*+[a-z]{2}/is', $email)) {
    $error['email'] = "Please enter a valid email address"; 
}

if (strlen($comments) < 3) {
    $error['comments'] = "Please leave a comment.";
}

if (!$error) {

    require_once('phpMailer/class.phpmailer.php');
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->From = $email;
    $mail->FromName = $name;
    $mail->Subject = "Contact Form";
    $mail->AddAddress($site_owners_email, $site_owners_name);
    $mail->Body = $comments;

    $mail->Send();



    echo "<div class='alert-box success'>Thanks " . $name . ". Your message has        been sent.<a href='' class='close' onclick='clearForms()'>&times;</a></div>";

} # end if no error
else {

    $response = (isset($error['name'])) ? "<div class='alert-box alert'>" . $error['name'] . "</div> \n" : null;
    $response .= (isset($error['email'])) ? "<div class='alert-box alert'>" . $error['email'] . "</div> \n" : null;
    $response .= (isset($error['comments'])) ? "<div class='alert-box alert'>" . $error['comments'] . "</div>" : null;

    echo $response;
} # end if there was an error sending
```

?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach using `header(..)` is on the right track. You just need to enable output buffering for the page to make sure that no content is sent to the user before the headers are manipulated.

Basically, make sure that `ob_start()` is called first on the page, before any other content is sent (ie. not HTML or `echo` statements before you start output buffering).

```
<?php

    ob_start();

    $name = trim($_POST['name']);
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $comments = $_POST['comments'];

    $site_owners_email = 'email@example.com'; // Replace this with your own email   address
    $site_owners_name = 'example'; // replace with your name

    if (strlen($name) < 2) {
        $error['name'] = "Please enter your name";  
    }

    if (!preg_match('/^[a-z0-9&\'\.\-_\+]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z0-9\-]+\.)*+[a-z]{2}/is', $email)) {
        $error['email'] = "Please enter a valid email address"; 
    }

    if (strlen($comments) < 3) {
        $error['comments'] = "Please leave a comment.";
    }

    if (!$error) {
        require_once('phpMailer/class.phpmailer.php');
        $mail = new PHPMailer();

        $mail->From = $email;
        $mail->FromName = $name;
        $mail->Subject = "Contact Form";
        $mail->AddAddress($site_owners_email, $site_owners_name);
        $mail->Body = $comments;

        $mail->Send();

        header("Location: www.example.com");

        echo "<div class='alert-box success'>Thanks " . $name . ". Your message has        been sent.<a href='' class='close' onclick='clearForms()'>&times;</a></div>";

    } # end if no error
    else {
        $response = (isset($error['name'])) ? "<div class='alert-box alert'>" . $error['name'] . "</div> \n" : null;
        $response .= (isset($error['email'])) ? "<div class='alert-box alert'>" . $error['email'] . "</div> \n" : null;
        $response .= (isset($error['comments'])) ? "<div class='alert-box alert'>" . $error['comments'] . "</div>" : null;

        echo $response;
    } # end if there was an error sending

    ob_end_flush();
 ?>
```

Comment: For this i get     Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by and the line is saying <?php is sending headers.

Comment: it's still sending, but not forwarding and causing the error.

Comment: What error? `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent` means there is some other content being sent before you call `ob_start`. Is your page included in another page? or does it include another PHP script?

Comment: i include header.php to bring in all my navigation on these the pages.  not on my sendmail.php but on the contact form, etc.

Comment: The `ob_start()` has to be called **before** anything else. If you are making the request to a page called `sendmail.php` then the very first thing in that file should be something like this: `<?php ob_start(); ?>` Otherwise, even if there are spaces in front of the `<?php` tag it could cause content to be sent (including the headers) to the client..

Answer (score 0):

It is

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com");
```

and not "locations"